# Can I display two language for ui in Blender at the same time?

Tags: interface, customization

Some of my students are learning blender right now, and English is not our first language, they prefer using Chinese for the UI.

And I know I can change the UI to the Chinese for them, but at the same time, I recommend my students to watch some awesome video tutorials on Youtube.

So, I try to find some way to display both the English and Chinese at the same time which will make my life much easier. And I think some features like displaying two languages for UI, can really help newbies to learn blender really fast, and this will be good to the blender community.

So, if you guys have any information that can help to do this, it will be great! And a big thank to anyone can help me~

Comment: Best solution I can come up with is to run Blender twice and set each instance to a different language then swap between them.

Answer (score 4):

I think a good solution is translate tooltips only:

[image]

Interface will stay the same, but if you want to know that some button or element do, you can hover cursor over this element and see the hint in native language.

[image]

Comment: Even if there was an option to enable other languages in tooltips its description'd have to be given in **all** languages. And how do you imagine it? Not everything can be done effortlessly and that's good.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I can't understand you. Blender has this option

Comment: And where exactly is this option? Prefs? And which version is that? I use 2.78.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth user preferences -> system. This option was here from 2.4x series.