# How can I togge between two languages?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, operator

I would like to switch between English and Chinese translation with a shortcut (Alt+E), and have it affect interface as well as tooltips and new objects (only translating tooltips such as recommended here would not be enough in my case: [Can I display two language for ui in Blender at the same time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124270/can-i-display-two-language-for-ui-in-blender-at-the-same-time))
I hope to achieve it with this script:

```
import bpy
class OBJECT_OT_CustomOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):



#bpy.context.preferences.view.language = 'zh_CN'
bpy.context.preferences.view.language = 'en_US'

 return {'FINISHED'}
```

So far, I have been manually running the line with the language I wanted to use. I couldn't figure out how to assign the shortcut, since it is in the user preferences. The upper part is copied from the operator simple template.
As I am new to Python, all help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that will add an entry to a custom operator to your preferences. By pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> you'll swap between the two languages defined in the keymap settings, by default Chinese and English.

Your mouse will need to be over a 3D viewport editor for it to work though. If you want it to work over other editors, you'll need to add other custom keymap entries.

```
import bpy


class INTERFACE_OT_swap_language(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "interface.change_language"
    bl_label = "Swap Languages"
    language_one: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="en_US")
    language_two: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="zh_CN")

    def execute(self, context):
        view = context.preferences.view
        if view.language == self.language_one:
            view.language = self.language_two
        else:
            view.language = self.language_one
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(INTERFACE_OT_swap_language)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.user
    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(INTERFACE_OT_swap_language.bl_idname, type='E', value='PRESS', alt=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note you can tweak these defaults by going into the preferences, looking for "Swap Languages" in the keymap search field and expanding the entry.

[image]

Here I've modified the second language property to swap to french for instance.

[image]

Sources :

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196518/86891

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyConfig.html#bpy.types.KeyConfig

Comment: I have tried the script and it works, thank you!
But what do I need to do to have it active by default? right now I need to execute it once in order for it to become active. If I create a keymap, export it and try to load it, I get this error message:
` Failed to load keymap 'C:\\Users\\elsch\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.3\\scripts\\presets\\keyconfig\\Chinese_English_Toggle.py'
`
How do I save it correctly to have it start up automatically?
Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSchulz you simply need to add a few lines to the script and then register the addon from the preferences > Addon > Install > yourfile.py see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html for the specifics